What's the proper method for modifying the default settings of a plugin in Lazyvim?
I'm attempting to use the sainnhe/sonokai plugin, which offers various variations and utilizes the sonokai_style option to switch between these variations. Here's my current configuration.
  {
    "sainnhe/sonokai",
    config = function()
      vim.g.sonokai_style = 'atlantis'
    end,
  },

  {
    "LazyVim/LazyVim",
    opts = {
      colorscheme = "sonokai",
    },
  }
}

That works. I was wondering if I'm doing it correctly or if there's a better way to set this up. I've tried using the opts = { sonokai_style = 'atlantis' } configuration, but it doesn't work.

Consider reading :help sonokai.txt!!
